# Number of query values and destination fields are not the same

Tags: c#-4.0, ms-access-2007

I have a problem, when i m run my code then error is occured that "*Number of query values and destination fields are not the same.*"

plz suggest me regarding that.

"*Code*"

```
 protected void btn_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:/Users/Geeta/Desktop/eTimeTrackLite1.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;");
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(str);
        conn.Open();
        string query = "insert into Employees (EmployeeName,EmployeeCode,DeviceCode,Company,Department,Designation,Grade,Team,Location,EmploymentType,Category,HolidayGroup,ShiftGroup,ShiftRoster,Dateofjoining,Dateofconfirmation,Status,DateofResigning,Sex) values ('" + txt_empname.Text + "','" + txt_code.Text + "', '" + txt_dcode.Text + "', '" + Convert.ToString(dp_company.SelectedItem)+ "', '" + Convert.ToString(dp_department.SelectedItem) + "', '"+Convert.ToString(dp_designation.SelectedItem)+"', '"+Convert.ToString(dp_grade.SelectedItem)+"', '"+Convert.ToString(dp_team.SelectedItem)+"', '"+Convert.ToString(dp_location.SelectedItem)+"', '"+Convert.ToString(dp_emptype.SelectedItem)+"', '"+Convert.ToString(dp_category.SelectedItem)+"', '"+Convert.ToString(dp_holigroup.SelectedItem)+"', '"+Convert.ToString(dp_shiftgroup.SelectedItem)+"', '"+Convert.ToString(dp_shiftroster.SelectedItem)+"', '"+Convert.ToString(dp_day.SelectedItem)+"', '"+Convert.ToString(dp_month.SelectedItem)+"', '"+Convert.ToString(dp_year.SelectedItem)+"', '"+Convert.ToString(dp_cday.SelectedItem)+"', '"+Convert.ToString(dp_cmonth.SelectedItem)+"', '"+Convert.ToString(dp_cyear.SelectedItem)+"', '"+Convert.ToString(dp_status.SelectedItem)+"', '"+Convert.ToString(dp_rday.SelectedItem)+"', '"+Convert.ToString(dp_rmonth.SelectedItem)+"', '"+Convert.ToString(dp_ryear.SelectedItem)+"', '"+Convert.ToString(rdbtn_male.Checked)+"', '"+Convert.ToString(rdbtn_female.Checked)+"')";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        BindGridData();
    }
```

"Thanks"

Comment: In your insert statement, you're specifying 19 insert parameters, yet trying to insert more like 25 from what I can see...

Comment: I m not getting what u r say ya i have 26 insert parameter in insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this query is that you are telling the query to expect 19 insert parameters(EmployeeName,EmployeeCode,DeviceCode,Company,Department,Designation,Grade,Team,Location,EmploymentType,Category,HolidayGroup,ShiftGroup,ShiftRoster,Dateofjoining,Dateofconfirmation,Status,DateofResigning,Sex)

But you are trying to insert more than that (26) - if you count the values that you're trying to insert you'll see that they don't match up.

So you can either remove the extra values in the latter half of your query, or add additional insert parameters. For example, you seem to be trying to insert a value for "year", "month", and "day" several times, yet you only have one date field. You should concatenate those together and convert to a date in order to get the insert working correctly.