# Getting error on INSERT: "Number of query values and destination fields are not the same"

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class form7
    Dim inc As Integer
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
    Dim dbprovider As String
    Dim dbsource As String
    Dim str As String
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim TotalRows As Integer
    Dim ID_Number As Integer

    Private Sub Form3_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        con = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Bank\db1.accdb ")
        con.Open()
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM accountsTable", con)
        Dim totalRows As Long = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        textbox1.Text = totalRows + 1000
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'Form5.Show()
        dbprovider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; dbsource=Data Source=D:\Bank\db1.accdb"
        MsgBox("Database is now open")
        'First_Name,Middle_Name,Last_Name,DOB,Age,Occupation,Marital_Status,Address,Account_Number)
        str = "insert into accountsTable values(" & TextBox1.Text & ",'" & TextBox2.Text & "','" & TextBox3.Text & "','" & TextBox4.Text & "','" & CDate(DateTimePicker1.Text) & "','" & TextBox6.Text & "'," & TextBox7.Text & ",'" & TextBox8.Text & "','" & TextBox9.Text & "','" & ComboBox1.Text & "','" & ComboBox2.Text & "','" & ComboBox3.Text & "','" & ComboBox4.Text & "','" & TextBox10.Text & "','" & TextBox11.Text & "','" & TextBox12.Text & "','" & TextBox13.Text & "')"
        cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(str, con)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Record is inserted")
        con.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        TextBox1.Text = ""
        TextBox2.Text = ""
        TextBox3.Text = ""
        TextBox4.Text = ""
        DateTimePicker1.Text = ""
        TextBox6.Text = ""
        TextBox7.Text = ""
        TextBox8.Text = ""
        TextBox9.Text = ""
        ComboBox1.Text = ""
        ComboBox2.Text = ""
        ComboBox3.Text = ""
        TextBox10.Text = ""
        TextBox11.Text = ""
        TextBox12.Text = ""
        TextBox13.Text = ""
        ComboBox4.Text = ""

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Me.Close()
        Form3.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image: Error]

Comment: What is the error???

Comment: The error is pretty clear you are passing 17 values and the table has a different number of columns.  Since you didnt specify the columns it might not update them right either.  The code has several issues, that I would camp out on MSDN reading all the examples there

Comment: The error is clear, but he managed to hide it pretty well :-)

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/SSJPN.png

Comment: The Error is :  Number of Query Values and destination fields are not the same .    ( cmd.ExecuteNonQuery())   you can see the picture from here

Comment: See the existing questions with this error: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29058093/466738, http://stackoverflow.com/q/10332899/466738

Comment: I used this but still showing me the same problem, (Number of query values and destination fields are not the same ) would you help me with it please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An INSERT statement of the form

```
INSERT INTO TableName VALUES (value1, value2, ...)
```

expects to be inserting a value into every column of the table. If you only want to insert values into *some* of the columns then you need to specify which columns they are, e.g.,

```
INSERT INTO TableName (columnA, columnB, ...) VALUES (value1, value2, ...)
```

Notes:

1. It is considered good form to *always* specify the column names.
2. You should be using a *parameterized query* instead of inserting the values directly into the SQL command text.

Comment: I used this but still showing me the same problem, (Number of query values and destination fields are not the same ) would you help me with it please?